# Elementor - Sort by name

Tags: query, sort

I have a website that lists paintings. All these paintings are made by various artists. I've added a custom post type "paintings" and created a form so each painting can be easily entered. What I want is a way to sort these paintings by artist.
I can't figure out the correct way to do this.

What I have done now is created the following query;

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/kunst_op_kunstenaar', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'kunstenaar_tekst');
  $query->set( 'orderby', array(
      'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
      'date' => 'ASC'
  ));
```

And that works, sort of, when adding a new artist this will get a new ID of course and will sort them on the last page, since the ID is the highest.

How can I create a query that will sort the artists the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about elementor, but to keep this as a Purely WordPress answer you need to change your query to sort by post name.  The code you provided looks like a pre-query filter so you should try this:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/kunst_op_kunstenaar', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'title');
}
```

This sets your order by function to sort by title and then order to ascending (a-z).

Comment: Thanks for the input! The big issue with this query is that it sort by artwork title and not by artist name.